# О "ботаниках"

Tags: этимология

Почему о "книжном черве", заучке говорят "ботаник"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кстати, отчет тут совсем не лежит на поверхности, и в данном случае слово "ботаник" не означает человека, занимающегося растениями, а просиходит от блатной фени, где "ботать" значит "говорить". То есть, ботаник - это человек, который умеет хорошо говорить.
А уже сейчас это прозвище стало больше ассоциироваться с этаким очкариком, собирающим гербарии.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно странно, что слово с явно позитивной окраской (ботающий на фене = свой, блатной) приобрело негативный смысл "оторванный от реальности".  
Касательно же школьного значения давным-давно высказывалась версия, что смысл тут в тычинках-пестиках, коими ботаники размножаются в отличие от реальных пацанов, предпочитающих половое размножение.

Comment: Смешная версия ))).

Answer (score 0):

Моя версия такая:в конце 80-х - начале 90-х в период расцвета видеосалонов в СССР в коком-то американском фильме о студентах, названия которого я не помню, был такой сюжет: все студенты занимаются любовью, и только один ( ботаник ) вместо этого ловит бабочек и собирает их в альбом, в конце фильма вместо бабочек он стал собирать в свой альбом женские трусы. После этого в МХТИ начали называть усердных студентов ботаниками.